# Decode Signature

Tags: apex, crypto, decrypt, blob, blob.topdf

I've one signature field containing encoded values like 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAApAAAACNCAYAAAAAYko8AAAAHGlET1QAAAACAAAAAA...' and i want to restore it back and put them into a list and display the signature as it was captured, in the page.

Please suggest me how to use Apex crypto class methods to solve my purpose.

```
<apex:page controller="AccountPDF11" contentType="image/png">
  <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.Hospital_Main)}"/>
  <apex:repeat value="{!m1}" var="key">
    <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:outputText value="{!key}" />
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!m1[key]}" var="c">
        <apex:column value="{!c.name}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!c.call_Date_vod__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!c.signature_Date_vod__c}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="signature">
          <apex:image value="data:image;base64,{!c.signature_vod__c}" />
        </apex:column>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:repeat>             
</apex:page>
```

Here is my code, had to avoid crypto class It's working fine, showing signatures, but I need this page in pdf and render as pdf not supported here. Please help me here.

Comment: is your signature base 64 encoded?You will need to use encoding.util to decode it back

Comment: Relates to [Decrypt base64 signature](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46427/decrypt-base64-signature).

Comment: Did you already try using the crypto class ? It would be helpful if you explain what is blocking you from solving this, so any answers aren't too general.